# How can I handle loggedInUser authentication and revoke authentication?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I dont know how to solve the code, i am VERY new to coding. Any help will be appreciated.

class LoginDataSource {

```
fun login(username: String, password: String): Result<LoggedInUser> {
    try {
        // TODO: handle loggedInUser authentication

        val fakeUser = LoggedInUser(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "Jane Doe")
        return Result.Success(fakeUser)
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        return Result.Error(IOException("Error logging in", e))
    }

}

fun logout() {
    // TODO: revoke authentication
}
```

}

Comment: Is the code you posted pseudo code or are you using some sort of library? In any case if you need to create user accounts I would recommend Firebase Auth, Its easy to implement and has great documentation...

Answer (score 0):

I think it is based on the API you have to call, it is project related.

Anyway, if you are just doing something to learn and there are no API, you could just save somewhere the credentials (like SharedPreferences or using a ViewModel) and delete them from there.

You could also relate to Android documentation to search something like this:

https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth

Hope it is usefull :)